# RTSP Source Filter with GDCL MP4 Muxer incompatibility

Tags: streaming, directshow, mp4, rtsp, multiplexing

I'm trying to use GDCL MP4 Muxer with my RTSP Source Filter. They work fine together except after stopping the graph, muxer doesn't finilize the file and write the reqiured tables to the end of file via file writer (some parts are written starting from moov but not the time table values). When I try another RTSP source filter (which I don't have its source codes), table values are created with GDCL MP4 Muxer.

But when I try Elecard's MP4 Muxer, it works fine with my RTSP Source Filter. So, there is an incompatibility. I examined GDCL's source codes but couldn't find what it was expecting from me. I already calculate and set timestamp values to samples using `SetTime` method. But GDCL still doesn't finilaze file. Is it caused by missing information or missing signal when graph stops? What can be the problem, any ideas?

Comment: You might need send EOS notification to the muxer in order to have it finalized the output file.

Comment: I agree and already tried that with DeliverEndOfStream() but it didn't work. And weird part is, "moov" section is being created at the end (about 600 bytes long) but only table values are missing. So, muxer knows that streaming is over but doesn't finish the job. Since these tables are meant to be the frame timestamp values etc., I suspected it was caused by missing time information. I added SetTime and some other muxers start working. I also tried to send media time. this time GDCL mp4 muxer crashed at the beginning of the stream, other muxers worked.

Comment: I think I'll debug GDCL mp4 muxer and see what's wrong. I asked the question if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Another thing I came across with GDCL Mux: you have to provide sample stop time. It might still sound good to only attach start time to a video frame, but this confuses the multiplexer. Or, you need to fix this within mux. This would however more likely leave an empty .MP4 file rather than incomplete, but it still is worth checking.

Comment: Finally!!! :) please write this as an answer so i can accept it. :D

Comment: p.s: I've already tried that with other muxers but probably my end time calculation method was wrong and some glitches occured. But when I was start time works ok alone, I forgot about this. thank you for saving a lot of debugging time. :)

Comment: I stumbled exactly on this myself a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should be aware of regarding Geraint's MP4 Mux is that it is checking incoming media samples to have both start and stop time. You might be having only `.tStart`/`AM_SAMPLE_TIMEVALID` which still makes sense for video, but this would be a problem.

So the samples have to have stop time, or you need to fix this in multiplexer code.

A typical symptom for the problem is that generated files are empty or of zero duration.